# Ken Burns effect on iPhone views

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, slideshow, transition

are there any exisiting approaches on how to apply Ken Burns slideshow effects
(take a look at a javascript demo: [slideshow demo site](http://www.electricprism.com/aeron/slideshow/)) to a view?

Regards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic concept is to set up the change you want applied to you view and then commit the animation.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:5];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: ...zoom, pan, whatever... cache:YES];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Cheers, niels

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any ready-to-use APIs, but you can easily create Ken Burnsish effects by animating an UIImageView's bounds attribute. Look up the animation API on UIView. Just a handful lines of code will do it.